# Logical level conversion with MOSFET-N

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, pwm

I doubt if the way I am converting the logical level is correct and if it is the best way to do this.

The PWM_1 signal comes from a STM32F4 microcontroller. When PWM_1 = logic level 1 I have 3.3V. When PWM_1 = logic level 0 I have 0V.

I need PWM_1's 3.3V to be converted to 0V in OUT_1 and PWM_1's 0V to be 5V on OUT_1 output.

As the SN74HC04D logic port is being powered with 5V it only recognizes logic level 1 when it has 3.5V in the input (according to the datasheet). So I need to do the logical conversion from 3.3V to 5V.

I would not want to use an integrated circuit for this, so I thought of that circuit with Mosfet-n.

I wonder if this is the best way to convert logical level without using integrated circuit.

[image]

Comment: What is the frequency of the PWM signal?

Comment: PWM frequency is 20KHz.

Comment: I'd use an SN74LVC1T45 level translator. Not sure why you need to do without IC's, it will certainly take more board space to do this with discrete components, and cost more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the 74HC04 with 74HCT04 and you don't need any other components. It will accept 3.3V levels and output 5V levels.

Comment: Excellent answer. Analyzing the 74HCT04 datasheet, I noticed that it recognizes logic level 1 with values above 2V. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIWXAV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You should mention that this circuit also **inverts** the PWM signal so the duty factor is changed.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson That's actually in the OP's requirements.

Comment: OK, I see, you are replacing the inverter as well, not just performing level conversion. You could improve your answer with a bit of text to explain it.